# CGAL - Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 -32 bit - Could not find the following static Boost libraries: boost_thread, boost_system

Tags: boost, cgal

I'm following the next installation guide:

https://www.cgal.org/download/windows.html#Boost

and got the following cmake error:

BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = C:/dev/libboost_1_67_0/lib32-msvc-12.0

BOOST_ROOT  = C:/dev/libboost_1_67_0/

```
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1483 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_thread-vc120-mt-1_67;libboost_thread-vc120-mt;libboost_thread-mt-1_67;libboost_thread-mt;libboost_thread;libboost_thread-vc120-mt-s-1_67;libboost_thread-vc120-mt-s;libboost_thread-mt-s-1_67;libboost_thread-mt-s
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1525 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_thread-vc120-mt-gd-1_67;libboost_thread-vc120-mt-gd;libboost_thread-mt-gd-1_67;libboost_thread-mt-gd;libboost_thread-mt;libboost_thread;libboost_thread-vc120-mt-s-gd-1_67;libboost_thread-vc120-mt-s-gd;libboost_thread-mt-s-gd-1_67;libboost_thread-mt-s-gd
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1483 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_system-vc120-mt-1_67;libboost_system-vc120-mt;libboost_system-mt-1_67;libboost_system-mt;libboost_system;libboost_system-vc120-mt-s-1_67;libboost_system-vc120-mt-s;libboost_system-mt-s-1_67;libboost_system-mt-s
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1525 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_67;libboost_system-vc120-mt-gd;libboost_system-mt-gd-1_67;libboost_system-mt-gd;libboost_system-mt;libboost_system;libboost_system-vc120-mt-s-gd-1_67;libboost_system-vc120-mt-s-gd;libboost_system-mt-s-gd-1_67;libboost_system-mt-s-gd
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1595 ] Boost_FOUND = 1
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1753 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.67.0

  Boost include path: C:/dev/libboost_1_67_0

  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

          boost_thread
          boost_system

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/modules/CGAL_SetupBoost.cmake:48 (find_package)
  cmake/modules/CGAL_SetupDependencies.cmake:85 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:674 (include)


Boost include dirs: C:/dev/libboost_1_67_0
Boost libraries:    
== Detect external libraries (DONE) ==
```

I have tryed many ways to solve the problem:

1. Using the binaries:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/

2. Compiling the boost:

C:\boost_1_67_0>b2 toolset=msvc-12.0 variant=debug,release link=static runtime-link=static threading=single,multi --prefix=C:\boost_1_67_0\build

C:\boost_1_67_0>b2 toolset=msvc-12.0 variant=debug,release link=static runtime-link=static threading=single,multi --prefix=C:\boost_1_67_0\build install

In all way the result is the same:

> libboost_thread-vc120-mt-gd-x32-1_67.lib,
>   libboost_thread-vc120-mt-s-x32-1_67.lib,
>   libboost_thread-vc120-mt-sgd-x32-1_67.lib,
>   libboost_thread-vc120-mt-x32-1_67.lib
>
> libboost_system-vc120-mt-gd-x32-1_67.lib,
>   libboost_system-vc120-mt-s-x32-1_67.lib,
>   libboost_system-vc120-mt-sgd-x32-1_67.lib,
>   libboost_system-vc120-mt-x32-1_67.lib

The problem is that cmake is searching for a lib with the name:

> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-vc120-mt-1_67

but the boost binaries only have:

> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-vc120-mt-**x32**-1_67.lib

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the FindBoost mechanism by specifying the path to your boost libraries with the -D option :

```
cmake -DBoost_THREAD_LIBRARY_RELEASE=C:/dev/libboost_1_67_0/lib32-msvc-12.0/libboost_thread-vc120-mt-gd-x32-1_67.lib -DBoost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE=... <path_to_CGAL_root>
```

or by specifying them in the GUI of cmake-gui, if you are using it.

EDIT: Apparently you can also upgrade your version of cmake to the latest version(3.11.2), which should have a FindBoost that works with Boost 1.67.0.